# Unable to run QT UIC as custom build tool

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

When I run the following command line, everything works
"c:\Tools64\Qt\5.1.0\msvc-2012\bin\uic.exe" -o "c:\cygwin64\home\admin\DiagdataAnalysis\GUI\Analysis\GeneratedFiles\ui_analysis.h" "C:\cygwin64\home\admin\DiagdataAnalysis\GUI\Analysis\analysis.ui"

The exact same command line when put in the custom build tool for analysis.ui does nothing. Yes, I see the description being displayed but the file is not created.

I tried changing the command line to "dir" and I did indeed see the directory being display. I also tried adding a "-v" to see the uic.exe version and again I saw nothing except the description.

For some reason, uic.exe does not work when run from visual studio 2012.
I am using QT version 5.1.0

Comment: Are you using absolute paths for the files? Did you add quotes around the variables?

Comment: I tried it with quotes as I posted in my original post. I also tried it without quotes. Currently, I have absolute paths (see my original post).

Comment: Since both of your questions appear to be answered by my original post, I'm guessing that I misunderstood your questions.

Comment: I was talking about the custom build tool configuration.

Comment: If you are talking about the "Command Line" field of the Custom Build Tool for analysis.ui, I am using the exact same string, character for character as I tried on the command line, as stated in my original post.

Comment: I don't think you are using the custom build tool as you should. Please read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx

Comment: No, that page describes exactly what I am doing. Please note. I have already said that the description is displayed, the UIC command just doesn't seem to do anything.Replacing the UIC command with a regular DOS command such as "Dir" does, in fact, do what it is supposed to do. Telling uic.exe to display the version with "-v" doesn't result in the version being displayed. In deed, passing bogus arguments to uic.exe doesn't cause any errors to be displayed. It is as if uic.exe doesn't do anything if run from the build tools.

Comment: Please note that this is the configuration set up by qt. The only thing that I have done is to replace the symbols and variables with fixed path specifications in order to get things working.

Comment: This used to work on another machine (which has since died). It is possible that it was using an older version of visual studio. Maybe there is some bug with visual studio 2012 and qt 5.1.0